# Linking to @see tag from within javadoc comment

Tags: tags, hyperlink, javadoc

I'm writing javadoc for a class and a particular paragraph has to be backed by an external link. My idea is to put this link in @see tag at the end of the class' javadoc and at the same time link the paragraph to the @see tag somehow, but I don't know how to do this. Maybe my approach is wrong and I should just include the link in the particular paragraph where is relevant instead of merging it with the rest of the @see tags section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `@see`Tag is to reference other classes. If you want a simple html-link to the internet use a html link in your documentation text:

```
/**  
* here comes a link <a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a>  
*/
```

you can also do this with the `@see` Tag infront of the html link to get the link listed at the bottom of your class.

Comment: I think it's not only for classes. You can see it here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#@see It talks about a "reference". In any case, I think I just repeated the link at the see section and in the appropriate part of the documentation.

Comment: right. I wanted to mention that `@see` only creates autogenerated links on classes or methods and not on web-links. Therefore you need to add the `<a href="...">